# What's the best max damage build for a goliath Fighter(weaponmaster)?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

My party composition is:

- Templar Cleric (wis/con, buffing/debuffing/healing).
- Fighter(Weaponmaster) (str/con, "tanking" role, axe+shield, mostly controlling and debuffing).
- Storm sorcerer (main DD, don't remember his stats exactly).

What's the best weapon, powers, and feats to maximize my DPR? We need another Fighter(weaponmaster) (with Goliath race, it's defined) that will be our 2nd DD (melee).

All sources are allowed.

Comment: Any particular reason you are doubling down on classes? A target can only be marked by one PC at a time. There are fairly durable strikes and usually a 2nd striker is the way to go before doubling up on any other role.

Comment: Let's say these are prerequisites... DM aloowed to change the build once, but races and classes should stay the same - and historically we got 2 weaponmasters...

Comment: Are you able to talk with your DM to change one of them to be something very similar story-wise but different in mechanical focus? The Fighter(Slayer) is a DPR machine while still being very similar in fluff to a Fighter(weaponmaster).

Comment: I can't access him now, but I think that the answer will be positive. What should I aim when building a high-DPR slayer?

Comment: To hedge bets I will first answer your written question, but then present the slayer as the better, alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can talk your DM into letting you hybrid barbarian (which doesn't have to change the backstory of your character one bit beyond "i'm a striker now!"), the [Stand and Bang](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3470256) build is fantastic.

If you can't get away with that, but can get away with a Slayer (which is still a fighter), go STR/DEX, take the full charge package (surprising charge, horned helm, vanguard gouge, badge of the berserker), at level 3 retrain into or at level 4 take the Martial Cross-Training feat to trade your second use of Power Strike for Rain of Blows. Take the utilities that let you break free of terrible status effects (which means train endurance). Be a werebear, and after level 10 use claw gloves to add +1d10 damage to all of your attacks. For PPs, Kensei is boring but effective, or feel free to be more creative.

If you are stuck as a weaponmaster, go greatweapon/two-handed weapon mastery, duplicate the above items as closely as possible, with the same charge package, rain of blows, and consider PMCing barbarian.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we've decided to go into Slayer with Gouge. As far as I understood the playstyle should be pretty simple here - just to hit with charges and finish the turn adjacent to enemy creature. But there are two consequences - I can't hit the same target twice without getting an OA and, actually, I can't attack without getting OA at all, am I right?

Comment: The badge of the berserker neck slot item causes movement made as part of a charge to not provoke opportunity attacks. You're correct that it's still potentially difficult to charge the same creature again on your next turn, but the level 2 item Boots of Adept Charging can help with that by letting you shift 1 after a charge. If you are focusing on an enemy that your defender-fighter has marked, it should only rarely choose to follow and attack you. Also, between a charge and rain of blows, most enemies should die before you want to charge again anyway, so you can just charge a new target.